# Scroll zoom broken

Tags: modeling

I have been using blender for only about a week and up till now when I scrolled i could fly around space freely. Then today I tried scrolling in and using shift middle mouse button to navigate. But now when i get close to the 0,0 point of the 3D space it slows down and stop so that I cannot cross over.

This is really restrictive and I don't want to have to settle with using it like this. How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a common thing with 3d software, luckily it is easy to 'fix' in Blender whenver it happens. Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and draw a selection rectangle around the place you want to zoom into.
This will do two things - zoom you into the rectangle you have drawn, and reset the scroll zoom amount.

Comment: I have found this answer but was hoping for a solution to get it back to how it was. Any ideas? I must have accidentally pressed something i shouldn't have.

Comment: Shift+B should also reset the scroll speed :o